# Ways to solve in integers $\frac{2x^2+5y^2}{xy-14}=11 $

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, integers

Consider the diophantine equation $$\frac{2x^2+5y^2}{xy-14}=11.$$ I have successfully found all its integer solutions, but in view of different equations, I was wondering if there are other approaches. I'll post mine as an answer.

Comment: I did not understand. This binary quadratic form must be infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @individ Real, yes. Integer, no.

Comment: @individ: Infinitely many **rational** solutions, sure (in the style of Pythagorean triples and such). That's when you are looking at rational points on a genus zero curve.

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite the equation as $$2x^2+5y^2=11xy-154 \\ 2x^2+5y^2-11xy=-154 $$ to note that decomposing $-11xy$: $$ 2x^2-xy+5y^2-10xy=-154 $$allows us to factor the LHS: $$  x ( 2x -y) - 5y (2x-y)=-154 \\ (x-5y)(2x-y)=-154.$$ Hence, as long as $154=2\cdot7\cdot11$, by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, we just have a few systems to care about:$$\begin{cases}
x-5y=\pm2 \\ 
2x-y=\mp77 \\ 
\end{cases}  
 \tag{1}$$ $$\begin{cases}
x-5y=\pm14 \\ 
2x-y=\mp11 \\ 
\end{cases}
 \tag{2}$$ $$\begin{cases}
x-5y=\pm22 \\ 
2x-y=\mp7 \\ 
\end{cases}
 \tag{3}$$ $$\begin{cases}
x-5y=\pm154 \\ 
2x-y=\mp1 \\ 
\end{cases}
 \tag{4}$$ $$\begin{cases}
x-5y=\pm1 \\ 
2x-y=\mp154 \\ 
\end{cases}
 \tag{5}$$ $$\begin{cases}
x-5y=\pm7 \\ 
2x-y=\mp22 \\ 
\end{cases}
 \tag{6}$$ $$\begin{cases}
x-5y=\pm11 \\ 
2x-y=\mp14 \\ 
\end{cases}
 \tag{7}$$ $$\begin{cases}
x-5y=\pm77 \\ 
2x-y=\mp2 \\ 
\end{cases}
 \tag{8}$$ which yield $(x,y)=(\pm9,\pm4),(\pm13,\pm4),(-43,-9)$.